# Use Sharepoint UpdateListItems without creating a new version?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

I wonder if anyone knows a "hidden" (=undocumented) feature, to update Sharepoint List items via the lists.asmx webservice without creating a new version?

(Update with new version works fine, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx)

I'm looking for a "overwrite" function or sth. like this?

Thank you very much!

powerbar

Comment: I don't know about through the webservices, but if you were to write your own webservice you would set the SystemUpdate=false on the list item and then call the items update().

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I can't write my own webservices, because we don't have that level of access to it (IT/Security reasons).